# match two sets of files to find closest relevance between them

Tags: nlp, data-science, tf-idf

I have two sets of files take it A and B, both sets have around 10000 files. I want to find the files in set B which are closest match for each file in set A.

Actually the files in set A and set B are actually directories but for simplicity I am referring them as files.

Currently I have written few parser to extract important attributes from both sets and storing them in database saying it as characteristics for each file in both types.

Now I would like to find the closest match for files in set A with files in set B.

Let me know your suggestions on the best approach to counter this problem.

Comment: What are your files like? How do you define this 'match' relation?

Comment: The files are technical files so lot of vocabulary is domain specific i.e networking. So 1 set of files are user generated and other set of file is system generated eg log files.
The match relation is my question what is the best way to define a match relation. tf-idf score and simple word match is the initial approaches I am thinking to implement. I was looking if there are any better way to do it.